# React Navigation | How do I change the buttons on a Tab Navigator from a child screen nested in a Stack Navigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a tab bar that looks like this:
[image]

The  two side buttons are stack navigators (Learn and Journal) and the middle button needs to navigate the Journal Stack, and depending on what screen in the Journal Stack  the user is on, it needs to say and do different things.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabBarIcon = ({ icon, title, focused }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        icon={icon}
        color={focused ? Colors.neutral[4] : Colors.neutral[6]}
        size={24}
        style={styles.icon}
      />
      <Text style={[styles.iconText, focused && styles.iconTextFocused]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const NullScreen = () => null;

const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Journal"
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        ...defaultNavOptions,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.neutral[3] },
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Learn"
        component={LearnStackNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon
              focused={focused}
              title={'Learn'}
              icon={faUserGraduate}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Null Screen"
        component={NullScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarButton: ({ focused }) => (
            <View
              style={{
                position: 'relative',
                bottom: 25,
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
                borderRadius: '50%',
                backgroundColor: 'grey',

                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                shadowColor: 'black',
                shadowOpacity: 0.3,
                shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
                shadowRadius: 3,
              }}
            >
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Alert.alert('hello world')}> // This is the button that I want use for useful things
                <View style={[styles.iconContainer, styles.paddingBottom10]}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faPlus}
                    color={focused ? Colors.neutral[4] : Colors.neutral[6]}
                    size={32}
                  />
                  <Text style={styles.iconText}>{'Add Sport'}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Journal"
        component={LogbookStackNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon focused={focused} title={'Journal'} icon={faPenAlt} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

And here is what the LogbookStackNavigator looks like:

```
const LogbookStack = createStackNavigator();

const LogbookStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <LogbookStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        ...defaultNavOptions,
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
      }}
    >
      <LogbookStack.Screen
        name="Screen1"
        component={screen1Component}
        options={defaultNavOptions}
      />
      <LogbookStack.Screen
        name="Screen2"
        component={screen2Component}
        options={defaultNavOptions}
      />
      <LogbookStack.Screen
        name="Screen3"
        component={screen3Component}
        options={entryScreenOptions}
      />
      <LogbookStack.Screen
        name="Screen4"
        component={screen4Component}
        options={SaveLogbookScreenOptions}
      />
      <LogbookStack.Screen
        name="Screen5"
        component={screen1Component5}
        options={defaultNavOptions}
      />
    </LogbookStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

I know how to use navigation.setOptions, but it only affects the immediate parent navigator, not the grandparent navigator.

Another thing I tried was to make the big circle button on the page itself, but it always rendered underneath the Tab Navigator. If there was a way to make it render above, I think I could just use that. I tried 'position: 'absolute', etc and it always rendered underneath the tab navigator. As it is, I had to basically make a dummy screen in the tab navigator to give me the button on top.

What I need to be able to do, is use big circle button on the Tab Navigator, to navigate to different screens in the LogbookStackNavigator. How do I do that?

Also, I need the title to change from "Add Sport" to "Add " depending on what screen the LogbookStackNavigator is on.  How do I do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. You have to use react-native-portalize. Just wrap the elements you want to be rendered  on top in a
 `<Portal></Portal>.` This will place it above a Bottom Tab navigator.

```
import { Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';

const FooterButton = () => {
return(
    <Portal>
      <View>
       <Text>I appear above the Tab Navigator!</Text>
      </View>
    </Portal>
);
export default FooterButton;
```

Don't forget to wrap the whole app in the the Host:

```
//In app.js
import { Host } from 'react-native-portalize';

const App = () => {
return (
    <Host>
       <NavigationContainer>
          <AppNavigator />
       </NavigationContainer>
    </Host>
)
}
export default App;
```

NOTE: The elements inside the Portal, do not clear when the navigator navigates to another screen. So to get around this, you have to only display the Portal, when the screen is active. Thankfully React Navigation 5+ provides a useIsFocused hook that accomplishes this perfectly.

```
import { Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const FooterButton = () => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  // Only display the button when screen is focused. Otherwise, it doesn't go away when you switch screens
  return isFocused ? (
    <Portal>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <View style={styles.footer}>{props.children}</View>
      </View>
    </Portal>
  ) : null;
};
export default FooterButton;
```

If you want a modal-style popup, you can wrap react-native-modalize and wrap it with react-native-modalize

[Thanks to livin52 on Reddit for the solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/kun6zq/comment/gitlbt7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)